# Filter one pandas dataframe using values from two columns of another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have the following two dataframes:

df1

```
   a1   b1         x        y
0  id1  1200.00    Meat     Client1
1  id2  240.20     Dairy    Client1
2  id3  -298.00    Veg      Client1
3  id4  10000.13   Fruit    Client3
4  id1  -569.13    Meat     Client2
5  id3  1000.00    Veg      Client5
6  id2  0.00       Dairy    Client1
7  id2  -32.00     Fruit    Client3
```

df2

```
   a2   b2         Category  
0  id1  1200.0013    1  
1  id2  -32.0115     4
2  id3  -298.0003    3 
3  id4  10000.1300   4
```

I want to filter df1 using

1. column a1 with values from column a2 in df2, and
2. column b1 with values from column b2 in df2 (approximate since rounding errors may occur)

This is the output I am looking for:

df3

```
   a2   b2         x       y
0  id1  1200.00    Meat    Client1
1  id2  -32.00     Fruit   Client3
2  id3  -298.00    Veg     Client1
3  id4  10000.13   Fruit   Client3
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) :

```
df3 = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        df2.sort_values("b2"), df1.sort_values("b1"),
        left_on="b2", right_on="b1", left_by="a2", right_by="a1",
        direction="nearest")[["a2", "b2", "x", "y"]]
      .sort_values(by="a2", ignore_index=True)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df3)

    a2       b2      x        y
0  id1  1200.00   Meat  Client1
1  id2   -32.01  Fruit  Client3
2  id3  -298.00    Veg  Client1
3  id4 10000.13  Fruit  Client3
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a merge, and you can use rounding without modifying the original data to get approximate matching.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Adjust precision for approximation
DECIMAL_PRECISION = 1

# Your original dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a1': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id1', 'id3', 'id2', 'id2'],
    'b1': [1200.00, 240.20, -298.00, 10000.13, -569.13, 1000.00, 0.00, -32.00],
    'x': ['Meat', 'Dairy', 'Veg', 'Fruit', 'Meat', 'Veg', 'Dairy', 'Fruit'],
    'y': ['Client1', 'Client1', 'Client1', 'Client3', 'Client2', 'Client5', 'Client1', 'Client3']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a2': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
    'b2': [1200.0013, -32.0115, -298.0003, 10000.1300],
    'Category': [1, 4, 3, 4]
})

# Perform the filtering
df3 = df1.merge(df2, 
                left_on=['a1', np.round(df1['b1'], DECIMAL_PRECISION)], 
                right_on=['a2', np.round(df2['b2'], DECIMAL_PRECISION)], 
                how='inner')

# Select the desired columns in the output
df3 = df3[['a2', 'b2', 'x', 'y']].sort_values(by='a2')

print(df3)
```

```
## OUTPUTS
    a2          b2      x        y
0  id1   1200.0013   Meat  Client1
3  id2    -32.0115  Fruit  Client3
1  id3   -298.0003    Veg  Client1
2  id4  10000.1300  Fruit  Client3
```

**EDIT**
I did a small speed test of all the methods presented in here so far. They're all pretty close, as one might expect.

```
%%timeit
## Method 1:

# Perform the filtering
df3 = df1.merge(df2, 
                left_on=['a1', np.round(df1['b1'], DECIMAL_PRECISION)], 
                right_on=['a2', np.round(df2['b2'], DECIMAL_PRECISION)], 
                how='inner')

# Select the desired columns in the output
df3 = df3[['a2', 'b2', 'x', 'y']].sort_values(by='a2')
```

3.16 ms ± 696 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
## Method 2:

df3 = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        df2.sort_values("b2"), df1.sort_values("b1"),
        left_on="b2", right_on="b1", left_by="a2", right_by="a1",
        direction="nearest")[["a2", "b2", "x", "y"]]
      .sort_values(by="a2", ignore_index=True)
)
```

3.65 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
## Method 3:

df3 = pd.merge(
    df1.assign(b1 = df1['b1'].round(0)).rename({'a1':'a2','b1':'b2'},axis=1),
    df2.assign(b2 = df2['b2'].round(0)),
    on = ['a2','b2']).sort_values(by='a2')
```

3.23 ms ± 427 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Thanks @MrChadMWood. It works! Very thoughtful of you to analyse the performance of your various solutions.

Comment: @Tipo33 I see others do performance analysis in these threads every  so often, and it seems like a decent practice for stackoverflow threads in general. I heard once, "code is read far more often than it is written." So, hopefully the small effort of a speed test can help the many readers who are sure to find themselves here in the years to come. Good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which rounds the values before merging.

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    df1.assign(b1 = df1['b1'].round(0)).rename({'a1':'a2','b1':'b2'},axis=1),
    df2.assign(b2 = df2['b2'].round(0)),
    on = ['a2','b2'])
```

Output:

```
    a2       b2      x        y  Category
0  id1   1200.0   Meat  Client1         1
1  id3   -298.0    Veg  Client1         3
2  id4  10000.0  Fruit  Client3         4
3  id2    -32.0  Fruit  Client3         4
```